# ASP .net Response Image rename

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, response

I have a problem with name of the image which is my application responding. I have some code which generate charts and then show them in html web page - we are using it in e-mails to customers. But, if anyone try to download the image it is named by the responding class.

I tryed this:

```
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "image/PNG";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attacment; filename=MyNewName.png");
            Response.BinaryWrite(chartImage);
            Response.Flush();
```

But this will imediately start downloading the image and i want only to show it.

I would be greateful for any ideas.

Comment: If your intent is to display the image, why don't you just use HTML and display the image using HTML markup? IE. <img src="image_path" />

Comment: To show the image in needs to be added to the body of the e-mails response.

Comment: I have an .aspx html page with following code:

`<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <img src="ImageID=1"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>`

Behind it runs .aspx.cs class which generate the chart image. I want to show it as response for the e-mail client. It works, but if i want to rename the image (from "class name" to some "custom name", I was told to use the ` "Response.AddHeader(" .... "); ` which is shown up. But it change the behavior of the web page. Insted of just showing the image, it starts downloading it.

Comment: So i figured out where was the problem.

I had to remove the word attacment from this line
` Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attacment; filename=MyNewName.png"); `

So this is working:
` Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=MyNewName.png"); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out where was the problem. I had to remove the word attacment from this line:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attacment; filename=MyNewName.png");
```

So this is working:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=MyNewName.png");
```